# ValueError: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: False

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have a example dict starting like this

```
{'first': {'second': [],
  'third': 1.0,
  'fourth': {'fifth': 'test', 'value': 2.0},
  'sixth': {'seventh': 3.0,
   'eight': 4.0,
```

I tried this

```
y_test = np.array([x['first']['sixth'] == 'seventh' for x in test_data])
```

when

```
test = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced').fit(X_test, y_test)
```

but keep getting

> **ValueError**: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the
>   data,  but the data contains only one class: False

**Note**: Cells 4 and 7 from [notebook](https://github.com/Puzer/stylegan-encoder/blob/master/Learn_direction_in_latent_space.ipynb)

edit: I changed it to

`y_test = np.array([x['first']['sixth'] == 'seventh' for x in test_data], dtype=float)` and now the problem is

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

for which I used label encoding

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn                        import metrics, svm
from sklearn.linear_model           import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import utils

lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
training_scores_encoded = lab_enc.fit_transform(y_test)
```

which goes to multiclass

or svc to keep the floats

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
svr = SVR()
sld = svr.fit(x_test, y_test)
```

but both these are taking a long time

using dtype=int takes 8 minutes on a t4 gpu
but the results have alot of noise and identity problems

Comment: It tells you exactly what the problem is in the error, you need samples of at least 2 classes, that means y_test has labels of only 1 class. Not sure why you re-assigning test and what does it have to do with the dictionary because no code suggesting it's even remotely used is added here.

Comment: you can see the cell from here, 4 and 7 https://github.com/Puzer/stylegan-encoder/blob/master/Learn_direction_in_latent_space.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, the error clearly mentions that there is only one label class.

You need to make sure that there are at least a couple of classes in the `y_test`. You can check the `y_test` array to make sure that there are two classes `True and False` before fitting to the model.

```py
# Sample y_test
y_test = array([ True, False,  True,  True])

# Check classes
set(y_test)
{False, True}

# In your case
set(y_test)
{False}
# Make sure your data has at least 2 classes
```

Comment: please see my comment above i gave simple example, see cell 4 and 7 here. https://github.com/Puzer/stylegan-encoder/blob/master/Learn_direction_in_latent_space.ipynb

Comment: Yes, I did check that. They are using some other dataset as it's different from the dict you're using. So add  `print(set(y_test))` to your code to check if you have multiple labels, which according to the error is not the case. You need to make sure that you are generating `y_test` properly.

Comment: I am currently trying to get ['faceAttributes']['emotion']['neutral'] for which if i do print(set(y_emotion_test)) I get {'0.171', '0.186', '0.839', '0.741', ...} for dtype='<U30'

Comment: note I set it like this y_emotion_test = np.array([x['faceAttributes']['emotion']['neutral'] for x in labels_data], dtype='<U30')

Comment: after looking at type(labels_data[0]['faceAttributes']['emotion']['neutral']) I get float, so dtype=float? but then I get ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous' error

Comment: the solution might be to under a label encoder in preprocessing but it is taking a long time

Comment: No. The problem is that you're trying to do classification on continuous data. LabelEncoding will take a long time as almost all the values will be unique. You need to create labels using thresh holding. Try something like `if x>0.5 then 1 else 0`

Comment: ok, although it took 8 minutes with dtype=int instead of float, which makes it binary instead of continuous, but the results have identity issues and alot of noise at higher coeff. What you are suggesting is essentially the same thing? What about using svr instead of logistic regression to get more accuracy by keeping the floats?

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution that works fast, 8s with a t4

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
sgds = SGDRegressor()
sld = sgds.fit(x_test, y_test)
results = sld.coef_.reshape((18, 512))
```